# Is every chain with strict order a lattice?

Tags: order-theory

If P is a totally ordered set (chain) with strict  order $\prec$ .. can we say P is a lattice ?. I mean we won't be having reflexivity at our disposal .. can we get over with it ? Can we show it otherwise ..

Comment: Lattice means each pair of elements has a least upper bound?  Chain means any two elements are comparable?  Unless you have other meanings in mind, "reflexivity" is irrelevant.

Comment: You can always define $x \leq y$ iff $x = y$ or $x \prec y$. Then $\leq$ is a partial ordering and you got "over with it". It is a lattice indeed.

Comment: @GEdgar there is a result that say in non strict partial order (Reflexive partial order) every chain is a lattice .. I am asking can we prove it for strict partial order as well ?

Comment: @amrsa but then that will change the relation ..

Comment: You'll have exactly the same Hasse diagram, so it doesn't add really anything meaningful. Of course you can also check that directly with your strict total order, but you'll have to accept that each member is both an upper bound and a lower bound of itself, and that's where the strict order is inconvenient; in practice, it corresponds to add the trivial pairs $\langle x,x \rangle$, with $x \in P$, which is what I suggested earlier...

Comment: @amrsa.   Thnx mate .. now it's making sense. I made a counter example for strict case.. so it doesn't hold In strict case .. but using your suggestion we can get over it ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An order $(L, \leq)$ is a lattice if for every two elements $a, b \in L$, $\exists \sup\{a,b\}$ and $\inf\{a,b\}$.
In a total strict order, as for instance a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, we can guarantee that the two previous conditions hold.